# How do I check for an element with a certain class?

Tags: reactjs, chai

My code under test has

```
<div className="foo">
    {this.props.foo ? "foo!" : ""}
</div>
```

and I want to test it like this:

```
it('shows no foo by default', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MyComponent/>
    );
    expect(wrapper).to.containMatchingElement(
        <div class="foo"/>
    );
});
```

However, it never finds the element and the test fails, even though the output shows my element:

> AssertionError: expected `<MyComponent />` to contain matching `<div class="foo" />`
>
> ```
>     HTML:
>     ...
>     <div>
>       <div class="foo"></div>
>     </div>
> ```

How do I assert that the `<div>` with the given class is in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('shows no foo by default', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <MyComponent />
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(".foo")).doTestHere(
        <div class="foo"/>
    );
});
```

Try This.

The way you wanted to try should be like this

```
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<div class="foo"></div>)).to.equal(true);
```

You have written incomplete test

Comment: Can you explain your answer? `doTestHere` gets an error, but I can get it to work with `.find(".foo").to.be.blank()`. It's still not clear to me why my approach with `to.containMatchingElement` did not work.

Comment: doTestHere means add your test code in place of that word.. upvote and accept my answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

[`containsMatchingElement`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/containsMatchingElement.html) is a method of Enzyme but the [`expect`](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) is an method of Chai.

So the two method are incompatible:

```
expect(wrapper).to.containsMatchingElement(<div class="foo"></div>); // incompatible!
```

You are supposed to use these methods like this:

```
expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<div class="foo"></div>)).to.be.true; // good
```